# Tunnelblick OpenVPN connection error

Tags: macos, vpn, openvpn

I'm running Tunnelblick 3.6.6beta02 (build 4581) OpenVPN client on OSX El Capitan.

The problem is, if I change wifi network, I couldn't connect to my OpenVPN server no and it says "Waiting for a server response..."

The only workaround is to restart computer or do the following command in the terminal, which is frustrating to do each time:

```
sudo ifconfig en0 down
sudo route flush
sudo ifconfig en0 up
```

Log

```
2016-08-16 11:03:48 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
2016-08-16 11:03:48 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1471334628,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,,,,
2016-08-16 11:03:48 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
2016-08-16 11:03:48 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2016-08-16 11:03:48 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:xxxx
2016-08-16 11:03:48 Socket Buffers: R=[196724->196724] S=[9216->9216]
2016-08-16 11:03:48 UDP link local: (not bound)
2016-08-16 11:03:48 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:xxxx
2016-08-16 11:03:48 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1471334628,WAIT,,,,,,
2016-08-16 11:03:48 write UDP: Can't assign requested address (code=49)
```

Comment: The same problem for me. You are not alone.

Comment: Same here. Got any solution?

Comment: @JinuKurian no, I just assigned hotkey combination to reload

Comment: @icherevkov: I need to turn off wifi and disconnect tunnelblick then do the "sudo route flush" then turn wifi back again. What did you meant by reload?

Comment: @JinuKurian running command `sudo ifconfig en0 down && sudo route flush && sudo ifconfig en0 up`

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Mac OSX, at least from what I can see in other similar posts. But no one seems to have the know how to fix this in Mac. Best thing I can do is restart my computer, which is kinda annoying

Answer (score 1):

The following fix it

- Turn off wifi
- sudo route flush
- Turn on wifi
- start TunnelBlick or VPN

Answer (score 0):

It appears removing the
user nobody
group nogroup

in the server conf file helps. You set up the routes as root, but when you disconnect you no longer have the rights to reflush.

Comment: So how to fix then?